# Datepicker displayed incorrectly

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to write an MVC.NET web-site and I want to use the `datepicker` component from jQuery. To use jQuery I am using the following code on my Layout page:

```
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.ui.all.css")" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

On the page where I want to use `datepicker` I use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
</script>
...
<div class="editor-field-search">
     <label for="fromDate">From date:</label>
     <input type="text" id="FromDate" name="FromDate" value=""/> 
</div>
```

But `datepicker` is displayed in a weird way:

[image: The way datepicker displayed]

I've Googled and tried to fixed, but have not find a way to fix my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not a JQuery master but people might need to know what `editor-field-search` and `fromDate` looks like.

Comment: editor-field-search is CSS class from standard MVC.NET project. fromDate is a field in my model class that should get value from this input.

Comment: Oki doki, I didn't see the asp.net-mvc tag.

Comment: You don't have the CSS referenced correctly. Run my sample http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1 and use the F12 tools and compare with your code to figure out why your CSS is not being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pure CSS reference problem. You don't have the CSS referenced correctly. Run my sample [Using the HTML5 and jQuery UI Datepicker Popup Calendar with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1) and use the <kbd>F12</kbd> tools and compare with your code to figure out why your CSS is not being used. – Rick.Anderson-at-Microsoft.com 
comment out my CSS reference and you get the same malformed calendar. The <kbd>F12</kbd> tools are great for figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are copy paste your source code here I  think you are missing a ">"

```
<label for="fromDate">From date:</label**>**
     <input type="text" id="FromDate" name="FromDate" value=""/>
```

Comment: Sorry. There were a ">" in my code, I accidently deleted during posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you close the `label` tag?

```
<label for="fromDate">From date:</label>
                                       ^
```

Comment: I accidentaly removed the ">" symbol when I was writing a question. This symbol is present in my code.

Comment: That would have been too easy. ;) Just as a test, if you comment-out all other html on the page except for the div containing the fromDate, do you still see the problem? (I'm wondering if some other style above the datepicker HTML is causing issues for you...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have downloaded a theme from jQuery's [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)...could try a couple things:

1. Use the jQuery and jQuery UI Javascript versions included in the download to
   make sure it is compatible (in js directory of download).  Looks
   like jQuery 1.7.1 is the latest version included in jQuery UI
   download and you have jQuery 1.7.2 on your page.
2. Try the jQuery UI css file in the css\custom-theme directory - it includes all the css needed for all the jQuery components.  Also
   check to make sure the images were copied next to the jQuery css
   file in your application like it is in the custom-theme directory.

[jQuery Getting Started Guide](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started)